# How to insert data in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I do changes in my code but it isnot working yet
  this is controller-submenu.php

```
class Submenu extends CI_Controller {


 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
     if (!$this->session->userdata('is_admin_login')) {
        redirect('admin/home');
    }
}

public function index() {
    $arr['page'] = 'submenu';

    $qry ='Select * from subcategory';
    $arr['submenu'] = $this->db->query($qry)->result_array(); 

     //$data['view']='edit';   

    $this->load->view('admin/vwManageSubmenu',$arr);

}



 public function add_submenu()
  {

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $cat = $_POST['category'];


    $result = $this->submenu_model->insert_subcategory($name,$url,$cat);

    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'insert successfully';
        redirect('admin/submenu/');

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'insert Failed';
    }

}
  $arr['page'] = 'submenu';
  $data['category'] = $this->submenu_model->get_category(); 
     $this->load->view('admin/vwAddSubmenu',$data);  

 }



 }
```

and this is model submenu_model.php

```
 class Submenu_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
   }
public function get_category()
 {
$query = $this->db->query->("SELECT * FROM category");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
 }

function insert_subcategory($name,$url,$cat)
 {
  $data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'url' => $url ,
    'idcategory' => $cat
);

$this->db->insert('subcategory', $data);
 }
 }
```

and this is view vwAddsubmenu.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/submenu/add_submenu">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Sub Category Name">
<input type="text" name="url" value="Sub Category URL">
<select name="category">
    <?php
        foreach ($category as $item)
        {
            ?>
            <option id="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"><?php echo $item['name'] ?></option>
        <?php
        }
    ?>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Sub Category">
```

Now the error is shown

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Submenu::$submenu_model

Filename: admin/submenu.php

Line Number: 56

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_category() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\application\controllers\admin\submenu.php on line 56
     How to solve

Comment: i see you didn't return the query in the model..  most of the user return a query after inserting data in to database.                                                                        
    <?php
     if(1){
    print("<pre>");
    print_r($records); //write your 'category' or the data which you want to fetch
    print("</pre>");
    }
    ?>    may be this help you using this you can see your data coming on not form database as array.

Answer (score 0):

On __construct function you have to include the model:

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

And call the model function in the controller like this:

```
$this->model_name->model_function();
```

Comment: public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
  
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
  
        $this->load->model("submenu_model");
         
    
        
    }
ichanged it but 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Submenu in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\application\models\submenu_model.php on line 63 error is shown

Comment: Follow instructions how to load model at this link: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html.
basically,  you may need to Uppercase model name when calling it: $this->load->model("Submenu_model");

Answer (score 0):

I have less than 50 reputation so I am not able to comment. So don't take my reply as answer to your problem.
Why are you doing this:-

```
$data['category'] = $this->submenu_model->get_category();
```

you are passing a active record to view. What do you want to do by doing this ? Why are you passing queries from controller to view. I think this is not a correct way.

```
$arr['page'] = 'submenu';

    $qry ='Select * from subcategory';
    $arr['submenu'] = $this->db->query($qry)->result_array(); 

     //$data['view']='edit';   

    $this->load->view('admin/vwManageSubmenu',$arr);
```

It is better that you can write queries directly in the view if you need some DB info in the view.
If you are using CI 3.X then the name of the controller file should be like "Submenu.php" first letter in capital.